# Typescript and jsx, why is a statically declared state null in the lifecycle of the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have two different projects, on one I'm using Redux and my components are declared as:

```
class Foo extends React.component<any, any> {
  public static state: any = {
    bar: ''
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(Foo))
```

and then I have a different project without Redux, where my components are declared as:

```
class Foo extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public static state: any = {
    bar: ''
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

I've tried declaring my state in a static manner on the redux project but it simply does not get picked up on runtime, can somebody give me an explanation for this?

EDIT:

It seems my question is not clear enough, some more code for clarification:

```
class Foo extends React.component<any, any> {
  public static state: any = {
    bar: ''
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state); // null <- why?

    return (...);
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(Foo))
```

whereas the non redux code:

```
class Foo extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public static state: any = {
    bar: ''
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state) // { bar: '' } <- works! why?

    return (...)
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `mapStateToProps` doesn't set the state of your component, it maps parts of your application state (in the redux store) to the *props* of your component.

The props that your component receives are the combination of the props from `mapStateToProps` and the ones you pass directly.

There are cases where it makes sense to have local component state, but one of the reasons to use `connect`ed components is to avoid this, instead storing everything in the global state, where it is updated by dispatching actions, rather than calling `setState`.

---

Referring to the update to your question, it looks like calling `connect` on your class breaks the way that `static` works, so you should probably just initialise your state in the constructor.

```
class Foo extends React.component<any, any> {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      bar: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state); // null <- why?

    return (...);
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(Foo))
```

Comment: Please check updated question, seems I was not clear enough on my question of state not being set when declared in a different manner. Props are fine, I know how to use connect and mapDispatchToProps, it is the declaration of the state that confuses me.

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry I can't provide a better explanation of what happens but I think that's the solution in any case.

Comment: yep, I know just declaring the state on the constructor works, thanks anyways!